# xtype tool doesn't have methode getType() extjs6

Tags: extjs

I've read [Extjs 6 documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.panel.Tool.html)  that `Ext.panel.Tool` have getType() method but when I try, it turns error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getType'

Why this error? Thank you

Comment: Can you please post your code where you're creating the tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked in the sources, and there is no *getType* method for panel tools. I guess that is a documentation issue. You can always access the *type* directly.